# Firebase auth and connection to database currently not working

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Im developing 2 apps currently in react-native and also implemented firebase services inside of both.

Yesterday everything worked fine, when I wanted to start testing my app today I could not log in anymore through any of my accounts in my app.
I thought maybe I messed up my code in my app so I launched my second app I didnt code on for about a week, I got the same problem here. Apps both just take around 20 sec trying to log in and then nothing happens anymore.

Is there a website or some sort of info where I can inform myself if firebase is currently down or not available? The problem definetly cant be on my side, it must be something with the servers.

Firebase console btw works, its just the whole communication from my apps to firebase itself.

Comment: _What_ is the problem? Are there any errors thrown?

Comment: Well now its fixed again. Didnt do anything, just waited for 2 hours and now I can login with my app to firebase again. This happens like once every 2-3 months. 

I cant reproduce the error message now anymore but it was something like "Cannot connect to the firebase servers right now. It seems your device doesnt have a stable connection, firebase will keep operating in offline mode" etc.

Comment: On the status question, see https://status.firebase.google.com/. I don't see any downtime recorded for the recent past though, nor did I see similar reports from others.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thats what I was searching for, thank you. 

Well quite strange I experienced this "downtime" on my side, will take a look into this status link once I should experience it again.